# Why does deleting "A=[13,20,7,12,10,2,5,1,0,18]" in line 7 of my program change the print(D) in the end?

Tags: python, list

Keeping or deleting line 7 in my program should not change the output, because I will only be assigning the same value to "A" twice. But deleting it changes the output. Here is the code

```
def C(A):
    A[1]=A[8]+A[4]
    return A
D=[]
A=[13,20,7,12,10,2,5,1,0,18]
Z=A
A=[13,20,7,12,10,2,5,1,0,18]  #When I delete this line, print(D) in the end gives different value . 
A[9]=A[3]-A[0]
if A[9]>0:
         A[2] = A[9] * A[1]
else:
    C(A)
    if A[1]>A[6]:
        A[2]=A[9]*A[1]
    else:
         while 2>1:
             C(A)
             if A[1]>A[6]:
                 A[2]=A[9]*A[1]
                 break
for x in range(0,len(A)):
    if (Z[x] == A[x]):
      D.append(A[x])
print(D)
```

If it is related to shallow memory Why does this code give the same output even when I delete line 3?

```
A=[13,20,7,12,10,2,5,1,0,18]
Z=A
A=[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
print(Z)
```

Comment: `A` initially refers to list 1, so `Z` refers to list 1 as well. Then you make `A` refer to list 2, but `Z` still refers to list 1.

Answer (score 1):

This shows the ID's of each variable through the assignments.

```
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> id(A)
19812552
>>> Z=A 
>>> id(Z)
19812552
>>> id(A)
19812552
>>> A = [1,2,3]
>>> id(A) 
19917160
>>> id(Z)
19812552
```

As you can see, when you reassign A to what it previously was it changes the address meaning it is no longer a shallow copy of Z, but rather a completely new list.

For the second part of the question, let's take 2 addresses (X and Y) and 2 variables (A and B):

```
A = [1,2,3] ( A now points to address X)
B = A (Z points to the same address as A, Z points to X)
A = [1,1,1] (A is now stored in a new address, address Y, B/X unchanged)
```

The second line causes no change to the variable B, so if you delete line 3, there is no change to the output.

Comment: @pundit I have expanded my answer

Comment: But the same thing could be said about the first question. A points to address X.       Z points to adress X.Then after new assignment. A points to adress Y . Z points to adress X then after I delete new assignment of A. Z should still point to X to give me the same answer